# Apex remove duplicate related records from list

Tags: apex, lookup, list, duplicate-value

Before inserting a list of new tasks into Task object , I need to make sure only one task for each WhatID is inserted.

Here's the sample structure. Task-1 and Task-2 have the same WhatID, then I should insert only Task-1 or Task-2.

[image]

I have these tasks in a list List and I am inserting the same list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd have to take out the duplicates before insertion.

## First Task Wins

```
Task[] tasksToInsert = new Task[0];
Set<Id> whatIds = new Set<Id>();
for(Task record: pendingTasks) {
  if(whatIds.add(record.WhatId)) {
    tasksToInsert.add(record);
  }
}
insert tasksToInsert;
```

The trick here is that `Set.add` will return true if the set was modified, or, in other words, the value being added was not already in the Set. If the value was in the Set, this method returns false, so we wouldn't add the task. In this scenario, Task-1 will be inserted, Task-2 will not.

## Last Task Wins

We can use a Map to keep track of the most recent task:

```
Map<Id, Task> tasksToInsertByWhatId = new Map<Id, Tas>();
for(Task record: pendingTasks) {
  tasksToInsertByWhatId.put(record.WhatId, record);
}
insert tasksToInsertByWhatId.values();
```

In this scenario, the map will remember the most recent record associated with the WhatId, and the old one will be evicted. In that case, Task-1 will enter the Map first, then be replaced with Task-2 after that. In other words, Task-1 will not be inserted, and Task-2 will be.